# Regular expression with a * in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to use a basic regular expression to check whether a string contains only numbers and alphabet characters so I tried

```
preg_match('[a-zA-Z0-9]*', $address)
```

Which unfortunately returns an error:

**Warning:** preg_match() [*function.preg-match*]: Unknown modifier '*' in **/bla/bla.php** on line **XX**

It's a simple regex. Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: `'/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/'` will do the trick. Are you sure, you need `*`, not `+`? Otherwise `$address` will pass the check.

Comment: No, it's not `+` he needs, but `^` and `$` anchors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern should begin and end with a pattern delimiter. Different preg options, like case-insensitive search can be added after the delimiter. Usually slash (/) is used for delimiter, but can be any symbol (the delimiter should be escaped in the pattern):

```
preg_match('/[a-z0-9]*/i', $address);
```

This will check if the string has numbers or characters in it.

If you want to make sure that it has *only* numbers and characters, then use this:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]*$/i', $address);
```

Comment: Edit: Corrected the character range (`A-z` matches some characters besides letters like `[`, `^` and others) and added `i` modifier. I also added anchors, or the validation will not work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm :) Can you give me a link to a tutorial for using regexps with php?

Comment: @Martin Marinov http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html . If you want to learn about Regular Expressions in general, go to their homepage. They have ***all*** the information you need.

Comment: The "i" modifier makes the regex match case insensitive so "a-zA-Z" can just be "a-z"?

Comment: @Psyrus Seems I was daydreaming. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Marinov: I usually use http://rubular.com/, which is a very quick way to build regexes and test them at the same time. It's very useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/ctype_alnum) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to find all possible alphabetic characters from different languages as well:

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{M}0-9]+$/i', $address);
```

But if just English then:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i', $address);
```

Comment: you forgot the `u` modifier ;) (and to notice that $address needs to be in utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $address)
```

Comment: "only numbers and alphabet characters" is waranted by `^$` the error shown comes from the missing slashs (or other `valid` char you want)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the slashes for the regex :

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/', $address)
```

http://www.ideone.com/G2TA3